# Dokku showing errors in console

Tags: node.js, docker, dokku

I have node.js app which I deploying with Dokku, for the first after deployment app crashed and Docker container closed, so I checked my project on my computer again and found error. How can I debug errors on Dokku? Is there any console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is to see logs of the container running your node.js app. But as the container is closed you cannot `attach` to it to see outputs from stdout and stderr.

You can however see logs of closed containers.

To do so, first run `docker ps -a`, this will output even closed containers.

Then use `docker logs <container-id>` with the id of the closed container to fetch logs and debug your app.

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier solution if you don't feel like messing with process management.

Dokku provide tools to help you manage your apps from the [client](http://progrium.viewdocs.io/dokku/community/clients/).
The dokku-toolbelt is installed with npm :

```
npm install -g dokku-toolbelt
```

Once installed, open the command line from your app directory (or `cd` to it).

Now that you are in the good directory, you can use `dt logs` to see the latest console log.

If you want more "real time" logs, type `dt logs -t`. You can now see every console.log() (and more) from you nodejs dokku app.

Happy debug !